# Pass active class to one of dynamically generated bootstrap tabs in django

Tags: python, django

I have read other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458239/django-template-tags-set-active-on-the-first-element-of-a-forloop-that-satisfi)) related to the same which suggested the use of custom template filters/tags but I have no idea how to implement the logic for this.

**note**: it is not a URL view so it does not have a request.

Here is the code that is generating tabs and of course the class active is being repeated in all tabs:

```
{% for day in day_list %}
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link active" id="{% cycle 'monday-tab' 'tuesday-tab' 'wednesday-tab' %}" data-toggle="tab" href="{% cycle '#step-one' '#step-two' '#step-three' %}" role="tab" aria-controls="{% cycle 'step-one' 'step-two' 'step-three' %}" aria-expanded="true">{{ day }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do you know the active day?

Comment: The one that is clicked becomes the active one. But after the page has loaded, the first tab should be the active one.